# Getting csrfmiddleware token in url

Tags: django, django-csrf

I am getting csrf token in the url after submitting my form like this.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/detail/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=lqvoeSG32IcodLTFksWEU1NPQ9XCmHybwmzMKEuPzxDN1e73B0JORpAGOcGGxsjH&symbol=FLWS

After making a GET request to view, the url is showing the csrf token in the url.

/views.py

```
def search(request):
    if(request.method=='GET'):
        form=searchform(request.GET)
        if(form.is_valid()):
            id=request.GET['symbol']
            data=company.objects.filter(Symbol=id)
            form=searchform()
            return render(request, 'list-company.html',{"data":data,"form":form})
```

/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from csv2db.views import Company,search
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('company/',Company,name='company-details'),
    path('detail/',search,name='search')

]
```

form in HTML file

```
{% block content %}
        <form method="get" action="{% url 'search'  %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_ul}}
            <button type="Submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% block content %}
        <form method="POST" action="{% url 'search'  %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_ul}}
            <button type="Submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

and change your view

```
def search(request):
    form=searchform()
    if(request.method=='POST'):
        form=searchform(request.POST)
        if(form.is_valid()):
            id=request.GET['symbol']
            data=company.objects.filter(Symbol=id)
            form=searchform()
            return render(request, 'list-company.html',{"data":data,"form":form})
    return render(request, 'list-company.html',{"form":form})
```

Comment: But what if i want to keep it 'GET' since i am using this form to get the dataset ?

Comment: well get method will always append the input type, so you cant do much much about that, else you need to use csrf_exempt in your view and remove csrf_token from form

Answer (score 2):

You are adding `csrf_token` template tag in the HTML file and form method is set to `get`. So data is appended as query parameters including csrf token.

So you can either change it to `post` method or remove the `csrf_token` template tag.